# Como hago para ordenar este dataframe a través de pandas por la columna 'CODIGO'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

ESTE ES PARTE DEL CODIGO, DONDE HE QUERIDO ORDENAR LOS DATOS Y NO HE PODIDO:

```
busqueda = f"SELECT CODIGO, PAIS FROM PAISES"
        rdtVal_dataframe = pd.read_sql(busqueda, conexion)
        rdtValOrdenado = rdtVal_dataframe.sort_values('CODIGO')
        
        
        print(rdtVal_dataframe)
        print(rdtValOrdenado)
```

NO HE PODIDO ORDENAR EL DATAFRAME ATRAVES DE LOS METODOS DE PANDAS, COMO HARIA, SE LOS AGRADECERIA. TENDRIA QUE AGREGAR ALGUNA FUNCION EN EL sort_values(), para que se ejecute el codigo como es debido.

```
   CODIGO   PAIS
0    2.3    CANADA
1    2.4    AUSTRALIA
2    3.10   EEUU
3    3.11   JAMAICA
4    3.12   POLONIA
5    3.6    BRASIL
6    3.7    VENEZUELA
7    3.8    MEXICO
8    4.1    ESPAÑA
9    4.10   ITALIA
10   4.7    COLOMBIA
11   4.8    PANAMA
```

`
SOY PRINCIPIANTE EN PANDAS.

DEBERIA QUEDARME ORDENADA DE LA SIGUIENTE MANERA:

```
   CODIGO   PAIS
0    2.3    CANADA
1    2.4    AUSTRALIA
2    3.6    BRASIL
3    3.7    VENEZUELA
4    3.8    MEXICO
5    3.10   EEUU
6    3.11   JAMAICA
7    3.12   POLONIA
8    4.1    ESPAÑA
9    4.7    COLOMBIA
10   4.8    PANAMA
11   4.10   ITALIA
```

Comment: Buen día, bienvenido(a) a [es.so], te recomiendo hacer el [tour] y leer la sección [ask]. ¿Qué has intentado hacer hasta el momento? Parte importante de la cultura del sitio es que los usuarios publiquen sus preguntas junto con lo que han intentado, de esa forma se demuestra que has hecho un esfuerzo por resolver tu pregunta/problema, de lo contrario probablemente la pregunta termine cerrada y/o votada negativamente. Lectura recomendada: [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Tiene pinta de que estás tratando de ordenar cadenas. Cual es el formato de la columa codigo? Por ejemplo, en el ejemplo mostrado, parecen ser todos decimales. Otro ejemplo de formato es una serie de números separados por puntos.

Comment: Buen dia Dante, el formato de la columna CODIGO es "string", osea son textos. Son cadenas de texto

Comment: Me refería al formato. Ese que me dijiste es el tipo, pero gracias igual!

Comment: Son del tipo "object", si me pudieras ayudar te lo agradeceria. Saludos y que tengas un feliz dia.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nota: esta respuesta es general. Si buscas una respuesta más precisa, me serviría conocer el formato de la columna código (ejemplo de formato: numeros enteros separados por puntos). No el tipo del DataFrame ni el de la base de datos.

---

Pandas es bueno, pero no puede adivinar como ordenar un dato. De hecho, lo que hace pandas cuando le decís "ordená esta columna" es usar un algoritmo especifico del tipo de dato, como pasa con los números.

Y sospecho que justamente a eso te estás enfrentando. Tiene toda la pinta que la columna CODIGO en la base de datos es de tipo cadena (el nombre exacto de el/los tipo depende de la base de datos, pero se refiere a esto mismo).

Los strings se ordenan, a resumidas cuentas, en base a su largo y la posición de cada caracter con respecto a la tabla unicode.

Una forma de indicar el algoritmo correcto es transformar la cadena en otro tipo de dato y ordenar.
Por suerte, pandas en el propio [sort_values](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) tiene el parametro `key`, que le podemos pasar una función que transforme la columna original en una serie con otros valores sin alterar los datos originales.

Por ejemplo, para el caso de un monton de numeros separados por puntos, nos conviene una lista de números enteros.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(["2.3", "2.4", "3.10", "3.11", "3.12", "3.6", "3.7", "3.8", "4.1", "4.10", "4.7", "4.8"], columns=["CODIGO"])

def sort_alg(value):
    return [int(part) for part in value.split(".")]

df = df.sort_values("CODIGO", key=lambda col:col.apply(sort_alg))

print(df)
```

Con key, hacemos "creer" a pandas que los datos a ordenar son los devueltos por la función pasada a key.
Por lo que pasamos de, por ejemplo, de ordenar en base a `"3.10"` a esto `[3, 10]`.

Comment: Muchas gracias, lo aplicare y ver que resultados obtengo. Que tengas una Feliz Noche

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu aporte, Dante, me funciono perfectamente. Que tengas una feliz noche. Saludos desde VENEZUELA